# line-height - то работает, то нет. Или от перестановки места "сумма" оформления меняется?

Tags: css

Почему так `line-height` работает:

```html
<div style="text-align:left; font:normal 9px 'Trebuchet MS'; line-height:10;">
  
  В лесу родилась елочка,<br>
  В лесу она росла,<br>
  Зимой и летом стройная,<br>
  Зеленая была.<br>
<br>
  В лесу родилась елочка,<br>
  В лесу она росла,<br>
  Зимой и летом стройная,<br>
  Зеленая была<br>
<br>
  Метель ей пела песенку:<br>
  «Спи, елочка, бай-бай!»<br>
  Мороз снежком укутывал:<br>
  «Смотри, не замерзай!»<br>
  
</div>
```

А вот так нет?

```html
<div style="text-align:left; line-height:10; font:normal 9px 'Trebuchet MS';">
  
  В лесу родилась елочка,<br>
  В лесу она росла,<br>
  Зимой и летом стройная,<br>
  Зеленая была.<br>
<br>
  В лесу родилась елочка,<br>
  В лесу она росла,<br>
  Зимой и летом стройная,<br>
  Зеленая была<br>
<br>
  Метель ей пела песенку:<br>
  «Спи, елочка, бай-бай!»<br>
  Мороз снежком укутывал:<br>
  «Смотри, не замерзай!»<br>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо посмотреть, что может делать [font](//htmlbook.ru/css/font):

```
font: [font-style||font-variant||font-weight] font-size [/line-height] font-family | inherit
```

Соответственно, все свойства, которые он потенциально может содержать, при его использовании затираются. Эта участь постигает и line-height.

Можно сделать так (заодно немного семантичность увеличил):

```html
<div style="text-align: left; font: normal 9px/10 'Trebuchet MS';">
  
<p>
  В лесу родилась елочка,<br>
  В лесу она росла,<br>
  Зимой и летом стройная,<br>
  Зеленая была.

<p>
  В лесу родилась елочка,<br>
  В лесу она росла,<br>
  Зимой и летом стройная,<br>
  Зеленая была
  
<p>
  Метель ей пела песенку:<br>
  «Спи, елочка, бай-бай!»<br>
  Мороз снежком укутывал:<br>
  «Смотри, не замерзай!»
  
</div>
```

Comment: а у line-height разве не надо размерность указывать?

Comment: @Grundy, неа, можно как множитель - так она немного более хитро наследуется. Хочешь, задай вопрос - отвечу :)

Comment: Ну по крайней мере сейчас, в хроме - разница разительная если указывать 9px/10 и 9px/10px

Comment: @Grundy, множитель - это не пиксель. Это что-то типа 10em. Но не совсем. Это именно 10.

Comment: ну так о том и речь :-)

Comment: @Grundy, ррррррррр)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, "заодно немного семантичность увеличил" - писать стили в коде - не может быть семантично ;)

Comment: @Николай, имелись в виду `p` вместо `br` для куплетов.

Comment: @Qwertiy `font: normal 9px/10` - ого! Как-то так досконально не изучал css! Спасибо. Теперь хоть более менее понятно стало.